# Surefire XML test reports for JUnit 5 test suites

Tags: junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I've just migrated to JUnit 5 and I can't see any test cases in the XML test reports for my test suites. I've written my test suites in the new JUnit 5 syntax for junit-platform-suite and the tests in my suites all run successfully.

This generates JUnit XML reports via Surefire. One XML file is generated for each test class, plus one for the suite. The XML file for the suite has no `<testcase>` elements in it and shows that no tests have been run, even though they have.

Does anyone know why this might be? Are there perhaps some differences in XML reporting in JUnit 5?

**Test suite class:**

```
@Suite
@SelectClasses({ LoggedOutSupportPageTest.class,
             LoggedInSupportPageTest.class
          })
public class SingleTestSuite {

}
```

**JUnit suite XML report structure:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/xsd/surefire-test-report-3.0.xsd" version="3.0" name="com.myorganisation.suites.SingleTestSuite" time="17.231" tests="0" errors="0" skipped="0" failures="0">
  <properties>
   lots of properties are here
  </properties>
</testsuite>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74225191/in-gitlab-ci-cd-how-do-i-get-the-tests-tab-to-correctly-show-junit5-tests-output is related I believe.