# In Gitlab CI/CD how do I get the Tests tab to correctly show junit5 tests output

Tags: gitlab, junit5

I'm trying to fully integrate our JUnit Suites into gitlab and struggling with the output on the "tests" tab.
[image: image of the test results]

What I have is a results summary given the `.gitlab-ci.yml` step, what I'd like is a breakdown of each tests name/time to complete/status.

When I look inside the TEST*Name_of_Test.xml I can see the individual tests with their time breakdowns:
[image: individual tests]

Here's what my stage looks like in the `gitlab-ci.yml` config:
[image: gitlab-ci.yml stage configuration]

Anyone have suggestions as to how I could properly configure the `gitlab-ci.yml` stage to get the broken-out unit tests run?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71999218/surefire-xml-test-reports-for-junit-5-test-suites Seems to be perhaps a part of why the results are not accurate?

Comment: AFAIK, you get the detailed breakdown that you are looking for by clicking on the job name (in the screen shot 09 QIE-Admin). GitLab keeps the grouping of the original input files (unlike Jenkins, which flattens all results into one list).

Comment: @user1010997, yes you are right, you do get the detailed breakdown by clicking on the step, but only if gitlab can correctly parse the surefire-reports....which it apparently can't do with junit5?  See my shell script below which de-nests the tests and allows gitlab to parse the results so that when you click on steps you get the correct test results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not a perfect solution.  This is a work around, see image result:
[image]

Here's what I had to do:

- Write a shell script to transform results to correct format -> https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/developer-for-zos/14.1.0?topic=formats-junit-xml-format

It looks like this:
**fixJunitReports.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

totalTime=0;
totalTests=0;
totalErrors=0;
totalSkipped=0;
totalFailures=0;
for testResult in $1/target/surefire-reports/*TEST*.xml ; do
   tsName=$(grep -Pio '<testsuite.*name="\K[^"]*' $testResult)
   tsTime=$(grep -Pio '<testsuite.*time="\K[^"]*' $testResult)
   totalTime=$(echo "$totalTime $tsTime" | awk '{print $1 + $2}');
   tsTests=$(grep -Pio '<testsuite.*tests="\K[^"]*' $testResult)
   totalTests=$((totalTests+tsTests));
   tsErrors=$(grep -Pio '<testsuite.*errors="\K[^"]*' $testResult)
   totalErrors=$((totalErrors+tsErrors));
   tsSkipped=$(grep -Pio '<testsuite.*skipped="\K[^"]*' $testResult)
   totalSkipped=$((totalSkipped+tsSkipped));
   tsFailures=$(grep -Pio '<testsuite.*failures="\K[^"]*' $testResult)
   totalFailures=$((totalFailures+tsFailures));
done

# Now build master file.
rm -f $1/target/surefire-reports/junit_report.xml
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>' >> $1/target/surefire-reports/junit_report.xml
echo '<testsuites id="junit_run" name="'$tsName'" tests="'$totalTests'" failures="'$totalFailures'" time="'$totalTime'">' >> $1/target/surefire-reports/junit_report.xml
tail --lines=+2 $1/target/surefire-reports/*TEST*.xml >> $1/target/surefire-reports/junit_report.xml
echo '</testsuites>' >> $1/target/surefire-reports/junit_report.xml
```

- Then I added it into the image that we use for builds:
  [image: Dockerfile]
- Finally I modified our stage slightly:
  [image: modified stage]